# Preprocessing a C header file

Tags: text-processing, files, c

I have a large header file which has many sections that are included or omitted depending on whether certain names are defined in the file.
For example lines like-

```
\#define A
\#define B 2
...
\#ifdef A
  ...
  ...
\#endif
...
\#ifdef B
  ...
  \#ifndef A
    ...
  \#endif
\#endif
```

I want to produce a file in which all sections that would be omitted, because of the names that are and are not defined, would be removed. I also want to remove single and multi-line comments from the output file.

I have tried

```
gcc -E Configuration.h > Configuration.i
```

but this only produces output such as-

```
1 "Configuration.h"
1 "built-in" 1
1 "built-in" 3
341 "built-in" 3
1 "command line" 1
1 "built-in" 2
1 "Configuration.h" 2
```

(I the above text each line is actually preceded by a hash character and the words built-in and command line are enclosed in angle brackets, but typing these characters in my message produces strange effects.)

Any suggestions as to how I might do what I want.  I would prefer not to have to write code or script to do this.

Comment: How do you expect it to be accomplished, without a code or script? Are you saying that a `gcc` command should work, but doesn't? In what way does your existing command fail?

Comment: This [so] Q&A might be a useful starting point: [How to apply a C preprocessor only to certain (#if/#endif) directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111354/how-to-apply-a-c-preprocessor-only-to-certain-if-endif-directives)

Comment: There is an unifdef(1) command to do exactly this. It is available in the Fedora repositories, and I'd be extremely surprised if it isn't in Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: As per steeldriver's comment, Stack Overflow has a more fitting community to answer programming questions, versus this site aimed at unix/linux OS questions. The sites are linked so your same account should work. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-P` option (inhibit generation of linemarkers):

```
gcc -P -E -xc input > output
```

Other interesting options are `-C` and `-fpreprocessed`; you can find them all in the `gcc(1)` manpage.